# How to do curve fitting of a curve family with python/scipy

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have a to solve the following problem:

- I want to fit a family of curves with one equation (see Code)
- Fitted Parameters (C1-C4) should be constants
- So I can fit (or describe) one curve of the family with just changing "Sigma and T"

I hope I could describe my problem, hope you guys can help, I would be very grateful!

Question Edited (Because of misunderstanding - 2020_04_04)

I’ll try to be more specific now, that for I have attached a picture where you can see an example of the “curve family” which changes for different “Sigma”. I want to describe those curve family with a pair of constants – C1, C2, C3 and C4 without changing them. The clue is to find an optimum of constants which can describe this curve family with just changing Sigma and T as variables. Therefor I have to fit the parameters for a bunch of curves with a minimum of error. Afterwards the equation should cover the whole family of curves by just changing “Sigma and T”.

[Example of Curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqEVf.jpg)

Best Regards!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


#Equation --> Eps_Cr = (C1*Sigma**C2*x**(C3+1)*e(-C4/T))/(C3+1)

def func(x, C1, C2, C3,C4):
    Sigma = 20
    T = 1
    return (C1*Sigma**C2*x**(C3+1)*np.exp(-C4*1/T))/(C3+1)

#Example Data 1
xdata = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
ydata = [0.000382,0.000407,0.000658,0.001169,0.002205,0.004304]

#Example Data 2
xdata1 = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
ydata1 = [0.002164,0.002371,0.004441,0.008571,0.016811,0.033261]

#Example Data 3
xdata2 = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
ydata2 = [0.001332,0.001457,0.002707,0.005157,0.010007,0.019597]

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')
plt.plot(xdata1, ydata1, 'g-', label='data')
plt.plot(xdata2, ydata2, 'y-', label='data')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)

plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r--',
         label='fit: C1=%5.2e, C2=%5.3f, C3=%5.3f,C4=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))


plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi! Please make your question more specific. What is your code doing, and what did you want it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the extra information you provided in the 'answer', it seems that you want to fit a hierarchical model. At least that is what statisticians often call them. Some parameters are shared between all data points (the parameters `C1` to `C4`, and some parameters are shared within the groups of datasets (`T` and `Sigma`). All these parameters need to be estimated from the data.

This is often tackeled by building a larger model for all the data, and in the model one select which of the groupwise parameters to use. If a data points belong to data group `1` we choose `Sigma1` and `T1` and so on...

Since you are already using `curve_fit`, I made a version of your code that does the job. The code style leaves a bit to ask for since I'm no expert in `scipy`, but I think that you will understand the method at least.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x_and_grp, C1, C2, C3, C4, Sigma0, Sigma1, Sigma2, T0, T1, T2):
    # We estimate one sigma and one T per group of data points
    x = x_and_grp[:,0]
    grp_id = x_and_grp[:,1]
    # here we select the appropriate T and Sigma for each data point based on their group id
    T = np.array([[T0, T1, T2][int(gid)] for gid in grp_id])
    Sigma = np.array([[Sigma0, Sigma1, Sigma2][int(gid)] for gid in grp_id])
    return (C1*Sigma**C2*x**(C3+1)*np.exp(-C4*1/T))/(C3+1)

#Example Data in 3 groups
xdata0 = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
ydata0 = [0.000382,0.000407,0.000658,0.001169,0.002205,0.004304]
xdata1 = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
ydata1 = [0.002164,0.002371,0.004441,0.008571,0.016811,0.033261]
xdata2 = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
ydata2 = [0.001332,0.001457,0.002707,0.005157,0.010007,0.019597]

#  merge all the data and add the group id to the x-data vectors
y_all = np.concatenate([ydata0, ydata1, ydata2])
x_and_grp_all = np.zeros(shape=(3 * 6, 2))
x_and_grp_all[:, 0] = np.concatenate([xdata0, xdata1, xdata2])
x_and_grp_all[0:6, 1] = 0
x_and_grp_all[6:12, 1] = 1
x_and_grp_all[12:18, 1] = 2

# fit a model to all the data together
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x_and_grp_all, y_all)

xspace = np.logspace(1,5)
plt.plot(xdata0, ydata0, 'b-', label='data')
plt.plot(xdata1, ydata1, 'g-', label='data')
plt.plot(xdata2, ydata2, 'y-', label='data')
for gid,color in zip([0,1,2],['r','k','purple']):
    T = popt[4+gid]
    Sigma = popt[7+gid]
    x_and_grp = np.column_stack([xspace,np.ones_like(xspace)*gid])
    plt.plot(xspace,
             func(x_and_grp, *popt),
             linestyle='dashed', color=color,
             label='fit: T=%5.2e, Sigma=%5.3f' % (T,Sigma))

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('fit: C1=%5.2e, C2=%5.3f, C3=%5.3f,C4=%5.3f' % tuple(popt[0:4]))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The output looks like this:
[image: output plot with fitted curves]

Finally, I want to add that `curve_fit` is not that well suited for this task if you have a lot of different groups. Consider some other library that could be relevant. Statmodels could be possible. One alternative is to reach for `scipy.optimize.minimze` instead, since it gives you more flexibility. You need to do the confidence interval estimation manually though...

I also want to add that the method above is overly complicated if you know the `T` and `Sigma` for each group of data. In that case we add the relevant value of `Sigma` and `T` to the x-vector, instead of a group id.

Comment: Wow LudvigH, I appreciate your effort thank you very much! I'll try to understand what you did there! I hope I can contact you when I have some questions.

Comment: No problem. Just remember to accept the answer and upvote if it answers your question. :)

Comment: Hi LudvigH, I think I understood what you did there. But I have to confess I'm a bit confused, if I want to reconstruct the equation (e. g. in excel) with the determined parameters, let’s say for xdata0/ydata0 by varying "x" now - the curve fit won’t work... my Y-Values (Results) do not even fit closely – why is that? In the code the fit seems to work.
Is it possible to check a greater area of parameters (there should be more than one optimum) and for C1 > 0? 

P.S.: Do you have some examples for Statmodels / scipy.optimize.minimze I could check on (for e. g. hierarchical models)?

Comment: Changed the plot and included the result of the regression in my anser. The method looks fine to me. Since I've answered your original question please accept my answer.

Comment: Open a new question regarding bounds handling (you can also read the docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) in curve_fit. That is a separate issue.

Comment: If the fit looks badly in Excel, that might indicate that either you are doing a mistake in excel, or that the model fits the data poorly, I think that https://physics.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is better suited for such questions.

Answer (score 0):

As per your query, I can understand that you need to fit one equation for three different datasets separately. So, I updated your code for the same by keeping sigma and T the same. Please have a look and let me know further.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


#Equation --> Eps_Cr = (C1*Sigma**C2*x**(C3+1)*e(-C4/T))/(C3+1)

def func(x, C1, C2, C3,C4):
    Sigma = 20
    T = 1
    return (C1*Sigma**C2*x**(C3+1)*np.exp(-C4*1/T))/(C3+1)

#Example Data 1
xdata = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
ydata = [0.000382,0.000407,0.000658,0.001169,0.002205,0.004304]

#Example Data 2
xdata1 = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
ydata1 = [0.002164,0.002371,0.004441,0.008571,0.016811,0.033261]

#Example Data 3
xdata2 = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
ydata2 = [0.001332,0.001457,0.002707,0.005157,0.010007,0.019597]

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data 1')
plt.plot(xdata1, ydata1, 'g-', label='data 2')
plt.plot(xdata2, ydata2, 'y-', label='data 3')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
popt1, pcov1 = curve_fit(func, xdata1, ydata1)
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(func, xdata2, ydata2)

plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r.',
         label='fit for Data 1: C1=%5.2e, C2=%5.3f, C3=%5.3f,C4=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))

plt.plot(xdata1, func(xdata1, *popt1), 'r+',
         label='fit for Data 2: C1=%5.2e, C2=%5.3f, C3=%5.3f,C4=%5.3f' % tuple(popt1))

plt.plot(xdata2, func(xdata2, *popt2), 'r--',
         label='fit for Data 3 : C1=%5.2e, C2=%5.3f, C3=%5.3f,C4=%5.3f' % tuple(popt2))


plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend(loc='upper left',prop={'size': 8})
plt.show()
```